# Auto flip randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, flip

I am creating an auto flipping effect on some boxes (which stop on mouse over). I have this code:

```
// Global flipping effect hooks
var flip_hook;
var delay;

// Flip and unflip panels
function startFlip() {
    $('div#front-page-mosaic .front-box.flip').find('div').stop().rotate3Di('flip', 500, {direction: 'clockwise', sideChange: mySideChange});
    delay = setTimeout( function() {
        $('div#front-page-mosaic .front-box.flip').find('div').stop().rotate3Di('unflip', 500, {sideChange: mySideChange});
    }, 8500);
}

// Autostart flipping effect
delay = setTimeout( function() {
    startFlip();
    flip_hook = setInterval(function(){ startFlip(); }, 17000);
}, 8000);

// Stop the flipping effect 
function stopFlip() {
    clearInterval(flip_hook);
    clearTimeout(delay);
}

// Stop flipping on mouse hover, restart on mouse leave
$('div#front-page-mosaic .front-box.flip').hover(
    function () {
        stopFlip();
    },
    function () {
        delay = setTimeout( function() {
            startFlip();
            flip_hook = setInterval(function(){ startFlip(); }, 17000);
        }, 8000);
    }
);
```

This works fine. But I want all boxes to flip start flipping different times, not all at the same time (although I want the flipping interval to remain the same). How can I achieve that? I tried to play with timeouts and intervals, but no luck... Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Might want to add a Random in there somewhere (to random the time before it starts).

Comment: I've tried to replace the 8500 on the stratFlip() by a random number, but it applies the same random number to all boxes, not a different random number to each one.

Comment: that is because you are selecting all of them with your selector

Comment: I have added a jsfiddle example... give it a look.

Comment: I'll have a look. Kind of works but need some fixes. Let's see what I can do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this in your `startFlip`

```
var boxes= $('div#front-page-mosaic .front-box.flip').find('div');
    $.each(boxes, function(i, box){
         //(Math.random() * 10) + 1 will random a value between 1 - 10 then * 1000 to get the time in milliseconds
         var time = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1) * 1000;
         setTimeout(function(){
               $(box).stop().rotate3Di('flip', 500);
         }, time);
     });
```

JsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/3gbksy2t/.
It's not 100%, but gives you an idea of what you need to do.